# error while compiling scribe2.2 with thrift 0.7.0 on ubuntu lucid and maverick

Tags: c++, thrift, scribe-server

I am getting following error while compiling scribe server on ubuntu.

```
In file included from store.cpp:27:
scribe_server.h:45: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual scribe::thrift::ResultCode scribeHandler::Log(const std::vector<scribe::thrift::LogEntry, std::allocator<scribe::thrift::LogEntry> >&)’
../src/gen-cpp/scribe.h:18: error:   overriding ‘virtual scribe::thrift::ResultCode::type scribe::thrift::scribeIf::Log(const std::vector<scribe::thrift::LogEntry, std::allocator<scribe::thrift::LogEntry> >&)’
store.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool ThriftFileStore::openInternal(bool, tm*)’
```

I am using scribe 2.2 with thrift 0.7.0
There were no errors while installing thrift.

Also I read in one post that this error is encountered while using older versions of thrift.  But I am using latest version of thrift.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem from thrift.

Solution: use thrift stable version

Copying literally Ying-Yi Liang words:

"I think this issue has something to do with a recent change in thrift 
(the git dev version). For a thrift snippet like: 
  enum X { 
      ... 
  } 
  X foo(); 
thrift used to generate this prototype for foo: 
  X foo(); 
but now it generates "X::type foo();", resulting in the error you 
encountered."

answered here: http://groups.google.com/group/scribe-server/msg/b17bda3b80706558